# get apk info from a sdcard file

Tags: android, apk

```
        String apkPath = apk.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "addApk(): apkPath = " + apkPath);
        PackageInfo localPackageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);
        localPackageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir = apkPath;//! null point exception
```

can't get apk's icon, name, version etc. I also tried the magic number 8192 instead of 0, but does not work either.
Any one have any suggestion? 
Thx in advance!

---

I changed my code to this:

```
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        if (pi != null) {
            ApplicationInfo ai = pi.applicationInfo;
            Drawable appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(ai);
            String appName = pm.getApplicationLabel(ai).toString();
            String appVersion = pi.versionName;
            String pkgName = ai.packageName;

            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "pkgName = " + pkgName + ", appName = " + appName + ", appVersion = " + appVersion);
            adapter.add(new InstallItem(pkgName, appIcon, appName, appVersion));
        }
```

and got output like this:

pkgName = com.chaozh.iReaderFree, appName = com.chaozh.iReaderFree, appVersion = 1.3.2.0 ...

as you see here, i can't get app name and its icon is always the default same icon.
I tired other installer in market and they works great, so any one tell me how to do? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this the correct answer, there are some tricks (SDK>8!):

```
public Drawable getApkIcon(String path){      
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();      
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);      
    if(info != null){      
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = info.applicationInfo;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8){
            appInfo.sourceDir = path;
            appInfo.publicSourceDir = path;
        }

        return appInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    }           
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is path?how to get it

Comment: It's the apk file's absolute path, like: String apkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                   + "/MyApp.apk"

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way**
Simply get the icon of any App using its `packageName`

```
public static final Drawable getIconOfAppUsingPackageName(Context context,String packageName)
{
 Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
 imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
 return icon;
}
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation. That would help use to understand logic behind answer.

Comment: @Luca just pass packageName of any app. it will give you the appIcon.

Comment: this only works for installed app. op wants application info from an apk in filesystem (sdcard to be more specific).